# Join the user transaction table with actula user table to display data for a particular day in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a user table 'tbl_user' with some columns like:

```
USER_ID
USER_FNAME
USER_LNAME
USER_GENDER
USER_DOB
USER_CAHANGE_DATE  ...etc...
```

I have created a trigger on this table so that when ever a value for a user is updated then I am storing that value with filed name into the transaction table like below:

```
USER_ID      FIELD_NAME     PREVIOUS_DATA      UPDATED_DATA   USER_CHANGE_DATE

1            USER_FNAME        test              test1           06/26/2013
1            USER_GENDER         M                F              04/26/2013
2            USER_DOB           01/01/2001       01/01/2002      03/01/2013
```

SO now, when user 2 want to see the actual data on 03/01/2013 I should display the data from tbl_user and join this transaction table to get the field values on or before 03/01/2013. In this case everything will be from tbl_user except USER_DOB is changed on 03/01/2013.

Can somebody help what is the best way to do it. I just need the method of developing, i don't need any queries.

Thanks

Comment: "I just need the procedure, I don't need any queries". Are you saying you'd like the method of developing a solution? Or are you saying you want the definition of a stored procedure?

Comment: method of developing...

Comment: Write a query which gives the top UPDATED_DATA (grouped by FIELD_NAME and ordered by USER_CHANGE_DATE), filter on USER_ID and USER_CHANGE_DATE. <-- That part's not straightforward. But if you've gotten that far, use it as a starting point for a PIVOT query.

Comment: I am struggling in writing the first query to group by and order by

Comment: So you do need queries?